# Android open specific facebook app profile page at other android app redirect to newsfeed page when facebook app is closed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to open certain Facebook profile page in my android app with specific user ID. 
My code opens facebook app if it is installed otherwise open webbrowser.
It works fine except when facebook app is installed and it is closed.
In that situation it just opens newsfeed page instead of the profile page. When the facebook app is open at background, it successfully redirect to desired profile page. How can I solve this ? Also is there an official facebook document which describes about the way to access facebook app URI ?

```
    try{
        this.getPackageManager()
        .getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0); //Checks if FB is even installed.

        final String facebookScheme = String.format("fb://profile/%s", user2FbID);
        final Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookScheme)); 

        facebookIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        startActivity(facebookIntent);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        String facebookScheme = "https://m.facebook.com/" + user2FbID;
        Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookScheme)); 
        startActivity(facebookIntent);          
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, Works for me

```
try
        {
            Intent followIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/<your profile_id>"));
            startActivity(followIntent);

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent followIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/<your profile_id>"));
                    startActivity(followIntent);
                }
            }, 1000 * 2);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/<user_name>")));
            String errorMessage = (e.getMessage()==null)?"Message is empty":e.getMessage();
            Log.e("Unlock_ScreenActivity:FacebookAppNotFound" ,errorMessage);
        }
```

Comment: This is happen if Facebook App is not running in background. I am also facing same issue and solve this by starting two activity, when First activity start then it enable Facebook App and after 2 Second same process is done then it open given Facebook Page/Profile

Comment: Thank you Singh ! It works ! Looks like you are calling the intent twice ? Could you give me some description that what are you trying in your code to solve my issue ? Thanks you saved my day..

Comment: In my app I am trying to open a Facebook Page and Facebook Group Page and by applying this I have solve my problem with displaying "News Feed" Page. @user3769783

Answer (score 4):

This was happening with me too. Updated the Facebook app and it's solved now, seems it was something to do in with Facebook. It's working properly now.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {
        try{
           // open in Facebook app
           context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
           return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/<profile_id>"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // open in browser
          return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/<profile_id>"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if I want to open Facebook application on specific post that I have its url / id?